# How to add Firebase Storage to existing Firebase project?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I created an app that I've been working on for 10 days. Initially, when uploading via github, I added Firestore and Auth modules. Now I need to add a Storage module in order to use the photos in the project. I see videos on YouTube how to add pods, but these videos are old. I also went into the podfiles, but did not understand which specific podfile to add the pod. Please advise how to implement this

I want to add Storage module to existing Swift project

Comment: Did you follow the process outlined in the documentation?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/start

Comment: yes, I did. there is nothing about how to add to existing project

Comment: Add the appropriate lines to your podfile and do `pod install`. That's about it. See [Cocoapods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html) which states - *Use pod install to install new pods in your project. Even if you already have a Podfile and ran pod install before; so even if you are just adding/removing pods to a project already using CocoaPods*

Answer (score 0):

1. Add  pod 'Firebase/Storage' to your pod file
2. Find your project in Finder. (ensure it is the ".xcworkspace" file, if some Firebase modules are already added) , or else use your app file.
3. Open options menu at your app file
4. Select "New Terminal at Folder"
5. And type "pod install"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQV4n.png)